# Access forms from their parent directive - dynamic form names and validation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

### INTRODUCTION

- I need to find a way to validate forms that are created dynamically in the `directive` which holds them all together.
- Validation errors should appear on form submit of each separate form, i have no problems displaying errors

#### DIRECTIVE

Contains multiple forms which are all submitted separately

```
app.directive('multiFormWrapper', function() {

    return {
        templateUrl: 'templates/directives/multiform-wrapper.html',
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            pageId: '@',
            attributeName: '@',
            multivaluedAttribute: '=',
            callbacks: '='
        }
    };
});
```

#### TEMPLATE

Only the important parts, look at the `name` and `ng-submit`

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="group in multivaluedAttribute">
    <form 
        name="{{attributeName}}EditForm{{group.index}}" 
        novalidate 
        id="{{pageId}}-form{{attributeName}}Edit{{group.index}}"
        ng-submit="callbacks.updateMultivalued(attributeName, value)">

        <div class="row" ng-repeat="field in group.fields">
            <div input-field-directive input-field="field"></div>
        </div>

    </form>
```

### PROBLEM

In order to achieve that validation messages appear on forms submit i would like send the data only if `form.$valid`:

```
ng-submit="{{attributeName}}EditForm{{group.index}}.$valid &&  
            callbacks.updateMultivalued(attributeName, value)">
```

But the name of the form is created in expression though.

### QUESTION

1. Is there a way to alias the form name somehow? (I don't think so)
2. Should i create another directive that would wrap one single form, get a handle of wrapped `FormController` within and override `submit`? It would be great if there is a way to do this without creating additional directive but for all form instances in the `link` or `compile` of `multiFormWrapper`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my approach was wrong, in [code.realcrowd.com](http://code.realcrowd.com/on-the-bleeding-edge-advanced-angularjs-form-validation/) blog post, the author is using an approach to replace `ng-submit` with custom directive in which he cancels the `submit` if form is `invalid`

```
app.directive('rcSubmit', ['$parse', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'form',
        link: function (scope, formElement, attributes, formController) {

            var fn = $parse(attributes.rcSubmit);

            formElement.bind('submit', function (event) {
                // if form is not valid cancel it.
                if (!formController.$valid) return false;

                scope.$apply(function() {
                    fn(scope, {$event:event});
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```